# Copying file dependencies

Tags: c#, recursion, error-handling

I have written the following code, and it works great, but I'm not satisfied. I really love the book "Clean Code" by Uncle Bob and I try to apply all his principles when coding, but I'm having a tough time cleaning this abomination. I call it an abomination because I'm sure everyone new to this method will spend more than 10 seconds trying to figure out what's going on. It's not easy to read. So I'm hoping for input on how to make it easier to read.

```
private void CopyFileDependencies(FileInfo fileInfo, string destinationPath, int recoveryAttempts = 1)
{
  try
  {
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(fileInfo.DirectoryName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
      File.Copy(file, file.Replace(fileInfo.DirectoryName, destinationPath), true);
    }
  }
  catch (IOException)
  {
    if (recoveryAttempts > 0)
    {
      KillProcess(fileInfo);
      CopyFileDependencies(fileInfo, destinationPath, --recoveryAttempts);
    }
    else
    {
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is a method that is ostensibly about "copying file dependencies" killing a process?

It also seems awkward to use recursion for something like this, especially from the catch block. Maybe it's just me?

I would get rid of the recursion and the process killing, and let the calling code higher up deal with that. This method should just attempt to copy the files from *a* to *b*, and the calling code can run it as many times as it wants, handle failures by killing a process or whatever, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If this method `CopiesFileDependencies` then I want to see the dependencies. So The general idea here is to name things in business terms. It's fine that the thing we're dealing with is a file, but so what? That's just an implementation detail. However if this method is already a well encapsulated, "rubber finally meeting the road" kind of code then there isn't much to fuss with.

Are we talking about "dependencies of a file" or "the dependencies are files?" If the former then I'd look upwards in the code structure and figure out just what this "file" is in terms of your domain and potentially rename some things.

- overview explanation comments. So I don't have to read it except for troubleshooting, let's say.
- `theException.Data.Add(fileInfo.ToString())`. ... or as appropriate, capturing method state at the point it blows up.

  - `foreach (var dependency in Directory.GetFiles(...`
- Rename `fileInfo` parameter to

  - `fileDependencies`  Or
  - `fileDependency`  Or
  - `fileDependenciesMetaData` OR
  - `fileDependencyMetaData`

    - because "metadata" sounds cooler than "info". And may be more precise in meaning.

Comment: Good point. I will change the first parameter to a sourcePath and rename the method to, CopyDirectoryContent instead and pull out the KillProcess.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you would want to kill the process no matter what to keep the process from eating memory, currently your else situation doesn't kill the process that is hanging.

```
catch (IOException)
{
    KillProcess(fileInfo);
    if (recoveryAttempts > 0)
    {
        CopyFileDependencies(fileInfo, destinationPath, --recoveryAttempts);
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Malachi, thanks for your response. It's essential that the "throw" is inside the else statement, otherwise the IOException will be thrown once all instances of the recursive method have returned. To your other point, you're absolutely correct, but the process is killed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that disturbs me the most is the fact that you're having a recurse after an exception is thrown. I would figure that after one error it wouldn't matter how many times you try to recover, unless the directory is actively receiving or removing files. I would just say that after the `IOException` is received, then quit the program, or handle it however you desire.

Here's how my implementation would probably be using `C++11`:

```
private void copyDependencies(FileInfo info, string dest, bool overwrite) {
    try {
        for (const auto &file : Directory.getFiles(info.getParent(), SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
            File.copy(file, file.replace(info.getParent(), dest), overwrite);
        }
    } catch (IOException err) {
        panic(info, err);
    }
}
```

One of the first things to be noticed about this are the case changes. Throughout OOP, the preferred method case is camel case, or the first word is lowercase and all subsequent words are capitalized. It's not critical to performance or anything, but I'm guessing it's what most developers will recognize first.

Second, I altered the loop syntax. In `C++11`, the `auto` keyword allows developers to create loops that look like something out of Java. Most can tell what's happening at a glance using this syntax. I forget specifically what's used in `C#`, but there should be something similar.

Switching focus to the copy method, I can only assume that the lonely `true` statement lingering in it is to allow an overwrite of some kind. Having it as a parameter in your method allows for greater external control, and since this method is essentially a `copy` method on steroids, developers using it have a greater understanding of what it's doing if they've using your `File` class before. Also, I can only assume that the `"*.*"` means `AllFiles`, so including it is kind of redundant.

And finally, the error handling. Most of this was explained at the beginning of this post. To expand on that, I would personally pass the error on to the method that actually handles it. I don't know the context that this method is used in, so I can't give a fully educated answer, but I believe that letting the `panic` method handle the error should benefit you in the long run.